# use ADDRESS function to define range in COLUMN

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have to use

```
=COLUMN($L$1:$CA$1)
```

as part of my original formula that CA, is the last column for a table named MyTable.
Because the last column is always changing (add columns every month),
i want to use

```
=COLUMN($L$1:ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(MyTable)))
```

but this is not work.
My question is: how can i add last column of a table to a part of specific range?

Comment: are you trying to get this in VBA ? or Excel Formula ?

Comment: Can you post an example of input data , and expected output data?

Comment: @ShaiRado, Excel Formula.

Comment: in the formula
=IFERROR(HLOOKUP(C213,$L$1:$CA$8,6,0)*G213*10^6,"")
CA is last column of MyTable that change every month

Answer (score 2):

`ADDRESS` returns a string. But the range reference in `COLUMN($L$1:...)` needs a cell reference after the `:`. `INDEX` will return a cell reference.

So try within your formula:

```
...COLUMN($L$1:INDEX(MyTable,1,COLUMNS(MyTable)))...
```

Comment: It dosn't matter whatever the second part after the `:` changes to, `column()` will return the number of the column where the range **starts** which is `$L$1`. What ever that `Index(...)` changes to the result  will stay 12.

Comment: @Peh: You are right for the formula `=COLUMN($L$1:$CA$1)` but I suspect @niksirat is not using this formula as it stands but as a part of a bigger formula where `COLUMN($L$1:$CA$1)` is in array context. There it returns the column numbers from `L` to `CA` as an array.

Comment: ahh I totally missed that `MyTable` is not a sheet but a formatted table inside a sheet, sorry (these are the same words in german). And yes you are right for the array context.

Comment: main formula is:
{=IFERROR(INDEX($L$1:INDIRECT(ADDRESS(1,COLUMNS(کل))),SMALL(IF(INDIRECT("L"&MATCH($C$204,کل[کد],0)+110&":"&"CC"&MATCH($C$204,کل[کد],0)+110)<>"",COLUMN($L$1:INDEX(کل,1,COLUMNS(کل)))-11),ROWS($C$211:C211))),"")}